# php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff won't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

This is what appears in console when i try to generate migration after creating entities
[image]
There is no migrations here :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install first this bundle:

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.0"
```

after you need to add the Bundle into AppKernel, launch `composer dump-autoload` to be sure and after you can use the command

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)